# Monitoramento de página com PHP

Tags: php

Olá,

Gostaria de saber se há alguma forma de monitorar uma página de um determinado site via PHP, constantemente...e sinalizar assim que a página for atualizada.

Eu encontrei um programa desktop que faz isso (WebSite-Watcher), mas preciso de uma solução online para que tudo funcione via browser.

Quem souber por onde posso começar me ajude...sou iniciante nos estudos em PHP.

Obrigado.

Comment: Você vai precisar usar `cURL` para obter o conteúdo da página e um `cron job` para executar o script de X em X minutos. Se a página mudar, o script envia um e-mail ou SMS para você. Essa é a ideia básica.

Comment: Que atualização você quer monitorar? Será que `header: last-modified` não resolve?

Comment: Amigos, obrigado pela ajuda...consegui encontrar uma solução via parser. Agora os convido para responder a minha nova pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/64665/ajuda-com-estrutura-de-repeti%C3%A7%C3%A3o-php-parser-simple-html-dom-php