# Ajuda com estrutura de repetição PHP - PARSER - simple_html_dom.php

Tags: php, dom, foreach, parser, while

Estou fazendo um parser com `simple_html_dom.php` onde puxo todos os links de uma determinada página. Eu consigo puxar os links e atribuir a um array, aí que vem o problema:

- essa página tem um limite de exibição máximo de 36 itens por página.
- os itens aumentam e diminuem esporadicamente...

**Exemplo da situação:**

Se a fonte que estou puxando o parser tem 133 itens, devido a limitação de 36 itens por página, terei que fazer o parser 4x alterando o número da página na URL para que a verificação seja feita até puxar os 133 itens totais.

**O que eu preciso:**

Pegar os 133 itens sem ter que especificar um limite estático para o contador, pois como os itens aumentam e diminuem, este limite tem que ser dinâmico e automático.

**O que eu já fiz:**

```
require ("simple_html_dom.php");

//define o limite de tempo do script como 0
set_time_limit(0);

//variavel que conta o total de links encontrados
$nlinks = 0;

//string que pega o valor atraves do parser
$string = '';

//array que pega o valor do parser
$toyota =array();

//contadores
$cont = 0;
$x=1;

/****************
    PRECISO QUE O A REPETIÇÃO ABAIXO (WHILE) SEJA REALIZADA ATÉ QUE 
    O ARRAY (TOYOTA) SEJA PREENCHIDO COM O TOTAL DE LINKS ENCONTRADOS
    SEM EU TER QUE ESPECIFICAR UM LIMITE ESTÁTICO PARA O CONTADOR...
    ISSO PRECISA SER DINÂMICO E AUTOMÁTICO, NO CASO ABAIXO COLOQUEI 4 ESTÁTICO
*****************/

//enquanto o contador for menor que 4 entra no laço
while($cont < 4){   

// get DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.webmotors.com.br/comprar/carros/novos-usados/'
.'sp-sao-paulo/toyota/?tipoveiculo=carros&tipoanuncio=novos-usados&anunciante=pessoa'
.'%20f%C3%ADsica&marca=toyota&vehicle1=%7B%22marca%22:%22toyota%22%7D&location=%5B%7B'
.'%22state%22:%22s%C3%A3o%20paulo%22,%22abbr%22:%22sp%22%7D%5D&precoate=170000&anode'
.'=2012&kmate=30000&atributos=%C3%9Anico%20dono&p='.$cont."&o=3&qt=36");

        //para cada link encontrado...
        foreach($html->find('a') as $e){
        $string = (string) $e->href;    

            //apenas verifica se o link nao tem a string "comprar/toyota"
            if(strpos($string, 'comprar/toyota') != 1){
                unset($html);
            }else{
                //verifica se o link tem a string "comprar/toyota"
                if(strpos($string, 'comprar/toyota') == 1){ 
                    //transforma a string encontrada em um link ativo
                    $link = "<a href='http://www.webmotors.com.br/".$string. "'>".$string. "</a>";

                    //echo $link."<br>";

                    unset($html);
                    $nlinks++;

                    //insere o link no array
                    $toyota[$nlinks] = $link;
                }                           
            }                       
        }
    $cont++;
    }

    //pega o tamanho do array
    $tam = sizeof($toyota);

    //enquanto o contador for menor que o tamanho do array
    while($x <= $tam){  
        //imprime o array na posição x
        echo $toyota[$x]."<br>";
        $x++;
    }

    echo "<br> ".$nlinks." carros da TOYOTA foram encontrados!<br>";
```

***A saída:***
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Quem puder da um help ae.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faça assim:

```
$html = true;

while($html){   

// get DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.webmotors.com.br/comprar/carros/novos-usados/'
.'sp-sao-paulo/toyota/?tipoveiculo=carros&tipoanuncio=novos-usados&anunciante=pessoa'
.'%20f%C3%ADsica&marca=toyota&vehicle1=%7B%22marca%22:%22toyota%22%7D&location=%5B%7B'
.'%22state%22:%22s%C3%A3o%20paulo%22,%22abbr%22:%22sp%22%7D%5D&precoate=170000&anode'
.'=2012&kmate=30000&atributos=%C3%9Anico%20dono&p='.$cont."&o=3&qt=36");
```

Porque?: porque quando o `file_get_html` não consegue a página deseja é retornado um `false`.

Obs: esse `false` deverá ser tratado pela a aplicação pois irá geral um `fatal_error` exemplo de tratamento:

```
if($html){
//para cada link encontrado...
        foreach($html->find('a') as $e){
        } 
}
```

Comment: tem apenas um detalhe...no valor de "file_get_html", no final da URL tem uma variável "$cont" que é o x da questão...pois ela precisa ser dinâmica, onde quando a mesma é alterada muda a página que eu estou verificando.

Comment: você pode incrementa-la

Comment: Então, como você pode ver no meu código ao final do "foreach" ele incrementa "$cont++" porém não está acontecendo...pois a minha verificação agora só puxa os 36 primeiros resultados

Comment: é porque você esta fazendo `unset($html);` faça isso somente depois do processo ser finalizado.

Comment: você sabe se tem alguma forma de acelerar o parse com simple_html_dom? pois nas verificações que estou executando leva em média...55 segundos para eu obter resultado, e as vezes ainda da o fatal error, tenho que ver porque...eu hospedei em um servidor para ir testando, confere aí se puder: [link]http://evolveti.com/paser/

Comment: melhorar a performance eu não conheço mas geralmente o `fatal_error` é porque o `file_get_html` não consegue a página deseja é retornado um `false` mas e quanto a questão foi resolvida?

Comment: De certo modo sim...estou usando a sua dica if($html) para tentar corrigir o problema do fatal error, mas em relação ao while($html) eu não consegui fazer funcionar desse jeito...aí deixei while($cont < 40) pois mesmo com um valor alto, o servidor php do host responde em tempo relativamente aceitável...media de 55 segundos...aí está funcionando só preciso ajustar agora a perfomace e tratar os erros. Obrigado!

Comment: porque não funcionou `while($html)` ? valide a resposta se ela foi util senão de-me mais detalhes =D

Comment: o meu contador não é incrementado dentro do while($html), aí a pagina pega apenas os 36 itens da primeira pagina sem percorrer as outras, eu tirei os unset($html) e mesmo assim não rolou...

Comment: Tem como incrementa-lo dentro do while não?

Comment: sim, mas acontece que ele só incrementa 1x...vai do valor 0 para 1 e sai do laço

Comment: sai do laço porque você esta fazendo `unset($html);` faça isso somente depois do processo ser finalizado

Comment: eu coloquei dentro do while($html) e dei //unset($html) olha o que acontece: http://evolveti.com/paser/toyota.php

Comment: Saquei, desmarque o unset, coloque o abaixo do cont++ uma instrução de controle onde você verifica se se há mais paginas a serem parseadas se sim você coloca um $html = true;